# Connecting to MySql database with Hibernate and Jersey

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jersey

I am trying to use Jersey for the first time and I get this exception when trying to run a Jersey server on the local machine:

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver </property>
        <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url"> jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username"> root </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"> </property>
        <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
        <mapping class="annotations.Person"></mapping>       
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Jersey's config.yml contains this part:

```
# Database settings.
database:
    # the name of the JDBC driver, mysql in our case
    driverClass: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    # the username
    user: root
    # the password
    password: 
    # the JDBC URL; the database is called DWGettingStarted
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
```

How can I fix this exception?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the `config.yml` file had some missing information.

Adding the following fixed this issue:

```
# Database settings.
database:
    # the name of the JDBC driver, mysql in our case
    driverClass: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    # the username
    user: root
    # the password
    password: 
    # the JDBC URL; the database is called DWGettingStarted
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
    # any properties specific to your JDBC driver:
    properties:
      charSet: UTF-8
      hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

      # the maximum amount of time to wait on an empty pool before throwing an exception
      maxWaitForConnection: 1s

      # the SQL query to run when validating a connection's liveness
      validationQuery: "/* MyApplication Health Check */ SELECT 1"

      # the minimum number of connections to keep open
      minSize: 8

      # the maximum number of connections to keep open
      maxSize: 32

      # whether or not idle connections should be validated
      checkConnectionWhileIdle: false
```